# How to get an image in a div with Cheerio and node

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I would like to get the src of an image in a div as shown below :

```
  const dataRepresentHackerNews = () => {
    request({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://thehackernews.com/2020/08/jenkins-server-vulnerability.html'
  }, (err, res, body) => {
    
    let $ = cheerio.load(body);
    let element = $('div.post-body')
    let title = $("h1").text()
    let img = element('img').attr("src");
    let article = $("div.articlebody").text()
    let hackerNews = []
    hackerNews.push({
     title,
     img,
     article
    })
    console.log(hackerNews, 'hackerNews')
  }
  )}
  dataRepresentHackerNews();
```

when I try to get the image, I always get the first one or nothing at all.
I've tried this code but I always get the first image of 'body':

```
let img = $('img').attr("src");
```

I would like make something like this:

```
let img = $('div.separator').$('img').attr('src')
```

bye

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want:

```
$('#articlebody img').attr('src')
```